# TS2339 error in a JavaScript file processed by the TypeScript compiler

Tags: javascript, typescript

In a project containing both code in plain JavaScript and TypeScript I have a `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "dom"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "outFile": "plugin.js"
  }
}
```

I don't understand the following behaviour of the TS compiler when compiling a `.js` file:

```
// error TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'a'.
function a() {
  const that = this;
  that.fun = function () {
    that.foo = 123;
  }
}

// but this compiles just fine
function b() {
  const that = this;
  that.foo = 123;
}

// this is also ok
function c() {}
const x = new c();
x.foo = 123;
```